# The customer does not re-enter back after exit

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a data extension and i have two primaryKey SubscriberKey and ContractID.

This DE is my entry source for JourneyBuilder.
In my JOURNEY
I have set up that the customer should only re-enter after he has existed.
And in the schedulation I put currency "All record".

The customer does not re-enter back after exit. what'is the problem?

Comment: How are you adding records to the DE whats the update method?

Comment: I add with query SQL in update

Comment: How did you schedule your journey? Recurring? On trigger with automations?

Comment: Recurring every day

Comment: Do you have a wait activity at the end of the journey? JourneyBuilder sets a default one to 1day at the end. When you do not change this, the customer might still be in that waiting activity. Maybe you could include a screenshot / more information. Its always better to have more information -> atleast when we want to solve it. currently we are only "guessing"

Answer (score 0):

Is the contact being evaluated?
click **View Event Results** on the entry source for number of contacts evaluated and number accepted.

Do they meet the defined entry criteria?